# PHP - HTTP authentication & download file (header)

Tags: php, http, authentication, download

I want know more about download a file when the directory is protected by a http digest authentication.

In fact when I use a PHP script that changes headers to directly download this file, I can download this file without needing to authenticate with HTTP authentication. Why is this? I'm running Apache 2.2 with PHP 5.3 on Debian.

Comment: Even after correcting all your typos I still don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: What header infos did you change? How did you download the file normally (if you say PHP downloads it directly)?

Comment: thanks for edit, I'm French...

Comment: I modify Content headers (4) and others before use readfile() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that the http authentication is set by apache, but the php script can access ANY file on your server, since it's a local read, not remote.

If you don't want your script to access the file if not authenticated you should implement the authentication also on the script, not only the files.

Comment: Ok thank ; so I must put the script file in the protected dir ?

Comment: The script itself has to [implement HTTP authentication](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php).

Comment: Do what Vatev said, implement that inside your script

Comment: ok but it's only useful if the php file is in the protected dir, right ?